# create a column which records userid SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to create a table in SQL where a column name ( something like userid ) records the iD of the person who modified the field.

can it be done and if so how.

Need an SQL script to create a table with a calculated column which automatically records userid

Please help

Comment: what do you mean of ID of the Person? do you mean the ID of Person's SQL Server User? or the ID of the Person which you have generated in your data model? BTW, sql-server is different than mysql, what db engine are you using?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I just want to know is it possible to record who did changes in the data.

Comment: I use microsoft  SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like a trigger.

as defined by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

A trigger is a special kind of stored procedure that automatically executes when an event occurs in the database server.

on your scenario, the trigger will save the user's ID once it is updated.

your question is a bit dim though, where would you get the username?

assuming the username is the login account in sql server

the script of the trigger would be something like this

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SaveUserID]
   ON  [dbo].[Employee]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    if UPDATE(employee_name)
    begin
        insert into auditTrail (username,useridChanged) 
        values (SYSTEM_USER,(select employee_name from deleted))
    end
END
```

The audittrail's column would be username and useridchanged.

Do take note though that this code is for Sql Server

Comment: Thanks a LOT joshua this is precisely what I was looking for